# ': [Errno 2] No such file or directoryile ' in Linux

Tags: python, linux, apache

```
-bash-3.2$ dir    
dispatch.cgi  stats
-bash-3.2$ ./dispatch.cgi
': [Errno 2] No such file or directoryile '
```

this is `dispatch.cgi`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7 
import sys, os
sys.path += ['/home/content/88/10907688/lib/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
sys.path += ['/home/content/88/10907688/lib/venv/bin/gccFishing']
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'gccFishing.settings'
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
WSGIServer(WSGIHandler()).run()
```

Why is dispatch.cgi not getting executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give the script the proper permission

```
chmod +x dispatch.cgi
```

and ensure that your path to python is correct

```
which python2.7
```

Comment: I have done chmod +x dispatch.cgi, but how do i check my python path with 'which python2.7' ? my path is /usr/local/bin/python2.7 but when i use it in any file it says bad interpreter

Comment: 'which python2.7' entered in your shell reveals the full path to python binary.

Maybe some incorrect line endings (windows instead of linux)